# creating a function that computes a metric for a subset of columns within a data frame.

Tags: r

Say I have a data frame.

```
level<-c(1:4)
A<-c(1:4)
B<-A^2
C<-A^3
d<-data.frame(level,A,B,C)
```

I then want to calculate the following metric for every column in the data frame, except the column labeled 'level'.

```
metric<-function(vector){
    distances<-abs(apply(combn(vector,2), 2, diff))
    sums<-apply(combn(vector,2), 2, sum)
    relativedistances<-distances/sums
    output<-sum(relativedistances) / length(distances)
    return(output)
}
```

So, this function can handle one vector at a time. What I REALLY want to do is hand the function the entire data frame, have the function compute the metric for each column except the column labeled level, and then return me a new data frame that has each column name, and associated metric. The output I want looks like this:

```
  observation    metric
1           A 0.3515873
2           B 0.5911614
3           C 0.7338014
```

Comment: Note- @agstudy's reply below is very close, however I would like to add code so the above function could take the data frame as an input, and output the final table, rather than execute two lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
xx <- sapply(d[,-1],metric)
        A         B         C 
0.3515873 0.5911614 0.7338014
```

You can format the result as a `data.frame`:

```
as.data.frame(xx)
         xx
A 0.3515873
B 0.5911614
C 0.7338014
```

Comment: this is close, but how do I integrate that into the above function, so I can run just 1 line of code, rather than two?

Comment: @Come on ! you can easily wrap it in another function!